# running lm on multiple columns of tibble with magrittr

Tags: r, lm, magrittr

I find it surprising that while this magrittr pipe works:

```r
with(mtcars,
     lm(mpg ~ qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2,"p.value",T])
```

and this expression works:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  summarise(across(one_of("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"),
                   ~ broom::tidy(lm(. ~ qsec))[2,"p.value",T]
  ))
```

applying a pipe breaks it:

```
mtcars %>% 
  summarise(across(one_of("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"),
                     ~ lm(. ~ qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2,"p.value",T]
))
```

with an error:

```
16: .handleSimpleError(function (cnd) 
    {
        msg <- glue("Can't compute column `{quo_data$name_auto}`.")
        abort(msg, call = call("across"), parent = cnd)
    }, "invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'", base::quote(drop && length(xo) == 
        1L))
15: `[.tbl_df`(., mpg, 2, "p.value", T)
14: .[mpg, 2, "p.value", T]
13: lm(mpg ~ qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% mpg[2, "p.value", T]
12: .Call(dplyr_mask_eval_all_summarise, quo, private)
11: eval()
10: mask$eval_all_summarise(quo)
9: withCallingHandlers(mask$eval_all_summarise(quo), error = function(cnd) {
       msg <- glue("Can't compute column `{quo_data$name_auto}`.")
       abort(msg, call = call("across"), parent = cnd)
   })
8: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
7: lapply(.x, .f, ...)
6: map(quosures, summarise_eval_one, mask = mask)
5: withCallingHandlers({
       for (i in seq_along(dots)) {
           poke_error_context(dots, i, mask = mask)
           context_poke("column", old_current_column)
           dot <- dots[[i]]
           dot <- expand_pick(dot, mask)
           quosures <- expand_across(dot)
           quosures_results <- map(quosures, summarise_eval_one, 
               mask = mask)
           for (k in seq_along(quosures)) {
               quo <- quosures[[k]]
               quo_data <- attr(quo, "dplyr:::data")
               quo_result <- quosures_results[[k]]
               if (is.null(quo_result)) {
                   next
               }
               types_k <- quo_result$types
               chunks_k <- quo_result$chunks
               results_k <- quo_result$results
               if (!quo_data$is_named && is.data.frame(types_k)) {
    ...
4: summarise_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by, "summarise")
3: summarise.data.frame(., across(one_of("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"), 
       ~lm(. ~ qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2, "p.value", T]))
2: summarise(., across(one_of("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"), ~lm(. ~ 
       qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2, "p.value", T]))
1: mtcars %>% summarise(across(one_of("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"), 
       ~lm(. ~ qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2, "p.value", T]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the cause of your problem. `dplyr::across()` works differently to `purrr::map()` when converting one sided formulas to functions.

`purrr::map()` uses `rlang::as_function()` to convert formulas to functions. Using this on your formula works fine.

```r
fun <- rlang::as_function(~ lm(. ~ qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2,"p.value",T])

fun
#> <lambda>
#> function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) 
#> lm(. ~ qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2, "p.value", T]
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "rlang_lambda_function" "function"
```

This means that the following works fine:

```r
map(
  mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp")],
  ~ lm(. ~ mtcars$qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2,"p.value",T]
)
#> $mpg
#> [1] 0.01708199
#> 
#> $cyl
#> [1] 0.0003660533
#> 
#> $disp
#> [1] 0.01314404
#> 
#> $hp
#> [1] 5.766253e-06
```

However, `dplyr::across()` uses its own code to convert formulas to functions:

```r
dplyr:::quo_eval_fns(rlang::quo(~ lm(. ~ mtcars$qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2,"p.value",T]))
#> function (.x) 
#> lm(.x ~ mtcars$qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .x[2, "p.value", T]
#> <environment: R_EmptyEnv>
```

As you can see, the '.' in your original formula is replaced with a '.x'. This issue happens in the `dplyr:::quo_eval_fns()` function:

```r
x <- expr_substitute(x, quote(.), quote(.x))
```

As a result, the function does not work.

There are a few workarounds you can use.

First, using `purrr::pluck()` makes the code a little simpler.

```r
mtcars %>% 
  summarise(across(one_of("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"),
                   ~ lm(. ~ qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% pluck("p.value", 2)
  ))
#>          mpg          cyl       disp           hp
#> 1 0.01708199 0.0003660533 0.01314404 5.766253e-06
```

Second, using R's new built in lambda functions also makes the code work.

```r
mtcars %>% 
  summarise(across(one_of("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"),
                   \(x) lm(x ~ qsec) %>% broom::tidy() %>% .[2,"p.value",T]
  ))
#>          mpg          cyl       disp           hp
#> 1 0.01708199 0.0003660533 0.01314404 5.766253e-06
```

You can also report this issue on the [dplyr Github repository](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues), because it is a genuine inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

Using matrix as DV in base R.

```
sapply(coef(summary(lm(cbind(mpg, cyl, disp, hp) ~ qsec, mtcars))), `[`, 2, 4)
# Response mpg  Response cyl Response disp   Response hp 
# 1.708199e-02  3.660533e-04  1.314404e-02  5.766253e-06
```

Using pipes:

```
mtcars |> 
  with(lm(cbind(mpg, cyl, disp, hp) ~ qsec)) |>
  summary() |> coef() |> sapply(`[`, 2, 4)
# Response mpg  Response cyl Response disp   Response hp 
# 1.708199e-02  3.660533e-04  1.314404e-02  5.766253e-06
```